# How can I find the C definitions for some variables in the system headers?

Tags: c

I'm looking for the C declarations in the system files for:

```
errno
stdin
stdout
stderr
sys_errlist
```

How can I find the definitions for each of these?

Comment: Use man pages. stdio -> `extern FILE *stdin;` (similar for stdout and stderr). errno -> `errno` can be a macro because it is local to thread or `extern int errno`. stdio -> `const char *sys_errlist[];`

Comment: didnt really understand..? I need to explain those declaration as they are in the C file system... @MohitJain

Comment: It may vary from system to system, so if you want specifics there's little point is us telling you what our system does.  You can simply create a file - say `x.cc` that includes the relevant headers, then run only your preprocessing stage - e.g. `g++ -E x.cc` or `cl /E x.cc`: you'll be able to see the declarations for those symbols and the exact header declaring it.  Alternatively, try e.g. `grep` on a recursive glob, or `find /usr/include -exec grep stderr {} \;` etc..  Sadly, that may not work if they're macros, but your compiler may have an option to leave macro definitions in.

Comment: DECLARATION or DEFINITION? declaration: header-files; definition: machine-dependant implemenation-source-file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stricto sensu, you cannot find the definition of `errno` or `stdout` *variables*. Some implementations of `<stdio.h>` had `stdout` defined by some macro. So it might not be a C variable, just a *name* ...! You just can be sure that it is, after an `#include <stdio.h>`, some "predefined" expression of type `FILE*` (actually an [l-value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_%28computer_science%29), since you can take its address).

In particular, `errno` is generally *not* a variable (because each thread has its own), at least not on most Linux systems. See [errno(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html). On my Linux/x86-64 system the *internal* `/usr/include/bits/errno.h` header (which should only be *indirectly* included via `#include <errno.h>`) contains:

```
extern int *__errno_location (void) __THROW __attribute__ ((__const__));
/* When using threads, errno is a per-thread value.  */
#   define errno (*__errno_location ())
```

A lot of standards related to C programming define names which are permitted to be macros or some compiler magic or [builtins](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html) (e.g. `va_args` from [`<stdarg.h>`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/stdarg.3.html)....). And nothing *requires* `<stdio.h>` to be a file; a standard conforming compiler could process `#include <stdio.h>` by some special code (which either sets up magically some names, or fetch some compiler state from outside, e.g. a database but not a file).

Answer (score 0):

there is a difference between "declaration" and "definition".

in short: "declaration" is for the compiler, while "definition" is for the runtime.

normally you find a "third-party"-declaration in the header files and more better in the man-pages.

the definition is abstracted away, because it may be depending on the machine-specific constraints.